# Does adding a photo make StackExchange/Overflow trust me?

Tags: discussion

I have been using Stack Overflow as a resource (yes amazing, thanks! etc), and suddenly woke up to the fact I can improve my skills by answering questions where I don't necessarily know the right answer, but it is one I need to work out in near future.

Today I received an extra hundred points in several different StackExchange sites because I am trusted.  This happened on the same day that I added my photo (just forgot to add it before, nothing personal).

So - does StackOverflow etc actually recognize good work across multiple sites, or was it updating the photo that tipped the balance? Or a bit of both?

I appreciate the points regardless, but was just wondering how the "we trust you working on multiple sites" bonus is triggered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have 200 reputation on one site in the network, if you have a user on any other site in the network, they all get an association bonus of 100 reputation.

This is what you have experienced.

Adding your photo on the same day is just a coincidence (or rather - given that you have decided to get more involved, you answered questions and changed your avatar to your photo - the result of answering questions gained you the reputation to put you over the association bonus limit).